# Unable to install PuLP in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, pulp

I have been getting error-messages when trying to install PuLP within my Anaconda environment:

> Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing
>   transaction: failed ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error
>   occurred while installing package
>   'conda-forge/label/cf201901::automat-0.7.0-py_1'. CondaError: Cannot
>   link a source that does not exist.
>   C:\Users\MarkKremer\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe Running `conda clean
>   --packages` may resolve your problem. Attempting to roll back.

I have tried all kind of this to resolve this issue, but nothing seems to work. The strange thing is that I have had PuLP working on this computer before, but somehow I managed to break it and can't get it fixed.

**What I've tried:**

1. Different commands to install such as `conda install -c conda-forge pulp` and `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pulp`)
2. Using `conda clean --all`, `conda clean --packages` etc.
3. Fully delete and reinstall Anaconda.
4. Format the harddisk and create a clean install of Windows 10.

None of these things seem to work. Does anyone recognize this problem or have any suggestions for possible solutions?

*I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10, with a 32bit Anaconda installation*

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to resolve the issue myself. In case anyone else is experiencing this issue, I'll share my solution:

**My solution:**

- Reinstall the *automat* package by running `conda uninstall automat` followed by `conda install automat`.
- Open Anaconda Promst **as administrator**
- Run `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pulp`